# hotmail doesn't accept my emails

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, email-bounces, ptr-record

I have installed and configure postfix as a mail server in ubuntu 12.04.
I can send emails to gmail with no problem but I can't send them to hotmail
when i enter in putty

```
dig @ns1glr.name.com mydomaine.com
```

i got this:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> @ns1glr.name.com mydomain.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 57399
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mydomain.com.                        IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mydomain.com.         300     IN      A       my.ip.add.res

;; Query time: 128 msec
;; SERVER: 184.172.63.127#53(184.172.63.127)
;; WHEN: Mon Dec 30 12:29:49 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 48
```

and when i check /var/log/email.log :

```
Dec 30 12:16:27 oxygen postfix/pickup[4657]: 3369D55E0D4B: uid=33 from=<www-data>
Dec 30 12:16:27 oxygen postfix/cleanup[4667]: 3369D55E0D4B: message-id=       <20131230121627.3369D55E0D4B@mail.mydomain.com>
Dec 30 12:16:27 oxygen postfix/qmgr[4658]: 3369D55E0D4B: from=<www-    data@mail.mydomain.com>, size=2321, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 30 12:16:27 oxygen postfix/smtp[4668]: 3369D55E0D4B: to=<sespoir@hotmail.com>,   relay=mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.92.184]:25, delay=0.61, delays=0.08/0/0.4/0.13, dsn=5.0.0,    status=bounced (host mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.92.184] said: 550 OU-002 (SNT0-MC4-F17)    Unfortunately, messages from my.ip.add weren't sent. Please contact your Internet service    provider since part of their network is on our block list. You can also refer your provider    to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors. (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
Dec 30 12:16:27 oxygen postfix/smtp[4668]: 3369D55E0D4B: lost connection with    mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.92.184] while sending RCPT TO
Dec 30 12:16:27 oxygen postfix/cleanup[4667]: CDB2055E0D4E: message-id=    <20131230121627.CDB2055E0D4E@mail.mydomain.com>
Dec 30 12:16:27 oxygen postfix/bounce[4669]: 3369D55E0D4B: sender non-delivery   
notification: CDB2055E0D4E
Dec 30 12:16:27 oxygen postfix/qmgr[4658]: CDB2055E0D4E: from=<>, size=4752, nrcpt=1  (queue active)
Dec 30 12:16:27 oxygen postfix/qmgr[4658]: 3369D55E0D4B: removed
Dec 30 12:16:27 oxygen postfix/local[4670]: CDB2055E0D4E: to=<www- data@mail.mydomain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.13, delays=0.03/0/0/0.1, dsn=2.0.0,  status=sent (delivered to command: procmail -a "$EXTENSION")
Dec 30 12:16:27 oxygen postfix/qmgr[4658]: CDB2055E0D4E: removed
```

Please help me, i have been struggling on this problem for 3 days
PS : I have a dedicated server from leaseweb.com with a public IP address

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the log you posted:

> Please contact your Internet service provider since part of their network is on our block list. You can also refer your provider to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors. (in reply to MAIL FROM command))

The previous owner of your IP address sent junk mail from it, and Hotmail has banned it.

Try putting your IP address in here:

http://www.anti-abuse.org/multi-rbl-check/

or

http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

They will tell you which blacklist services have your address mentioned and maybe why. Each blacklist service has a different way of asking to be removed - you will have to look through their websites to work out how. Once you have your address removed from blacklists, Hotmail will very likely start accepting email from you.

Comment: hello, my ip is black listed here http://cbl.abuseat.org/ what should i do?

Comment: @ArhHokagi The **very first piece of text on that page** is "I'm listed, what do I do?"

Comment: I have solved this problem by installing dkim and add an appropriete spf record